Identify 60s-70s Extra / Character Actor: Chiseled Face, Red Hair, Large Ears





This uncredited mystery man appeared as a photographer on the Brady Bunch episodes "Tell It Like It Is" (S02E24-1971) and "The Teeter Totter Caper" (S03E14-1971).  As an extra, he never spoke in either episode (but he did leer quite convincingly at Mrs. Brady in her bathrobe)!
He also appeared on The Odd Couple TV episode "What does a Naked Lady Say to You?" (S01E23-1971) as the man in the bathtub during the police raid of an R-rated play at the very close of the episode.  Again, uncredited.
Finally, seven years earlier this man briefly appeared as an extra in the movie "Good Neighbor Sam" (1964) as a man walking with his wife on the street scowling at the camera during the scene in which Bernie Kopell was getting candid shots outside the entrance to the advertising agency.  In this early 1964 appearance, he seemed to have a muscular body builder appearance under his suit despite his diminutive stature (if that helps any).  This was not true in his 1971 appearances - his build seemed more normal.

Again, all appearances of course uncredited with nary a shred of evidence as to his identity to be found on this planet, despite his almost strikingly anomalous facade.  Both the Brady Bunch and The Odd Couple were ABC / Paramount productions, being shot around the same time - that may be another clue to his identity.
Relying on the great minds and vast expertise at stackexchange to help solve this years old mystery.
Many, many thanks in advance for your help!
P.S. Added still shots from Good Neighbor Sam (1964 - Street Scene) and The Odd Couple (1971 - Bathtub Scene).  I assure you these are all the same man and your continued comments and inputs to help solve this mystery are greatly appreciated!
Please note - this actor is NOT Jonathan Hole.

Maybe no help at all, but I'm sure I know that face, even though I doubt I've seen any of your references; so that may not be the limit of his work.

Though I'm usually not a fan of actor ID questions, this is definitely one of the better examples.

Can you post the other stills too, maybe upload them to an image hoster.

I know it's not him, but he does remind me of Jack Gilford, he of Cocoon fame.

The second shot from the OP sure looks a lot like Jason Robards. However, I don't see any mention of the Brady Bunch on his IMDB filmography. He also doesn't have red hair, but it could have been dyed for the part.

@BrettFromLA So are you saying these 2 pictures are of 2 different guys? (Seeing that the 1st picture looks nothing like Robards...)

@Walt No, you're right, the first picture looks nothing like Robards!

How did you find these pictures? Did you type the names of movies and TV shows , and sifted through the stills? What's your secret?!

I think this elusive guy may be Harvey Miller. In the book, The Odd Couple on Stage and Screen: A History with Cast and Crew Profiles and an Episode Guide, he is credited as appearing as the "rubber ducky" under the name Harvey Skolnik. He was a comedy writer. He actually was a producer and director as well. He's gone now thou. 
Also he appears in Season 3, Episode 1 Gloria, Hallelujah credited as Skolnik again.

I'm afraid this is Harvey Miller.
